# Posting xml to SOAP service

Tags: php, xml, post, soap

I'm fairly new to SOAP and PHP and I'm having some troubles, that I hope someone here on Stack Overflow can help me with.

I'm trying to use this code to post a xml file (retursvar.xml).

I'm using this code to post the file:

```
<?php
$url = "https://someserver/somefunction";

$options = array(
                'login' => 'someusername',
                'password' => 'somepassword',
                'trace' => 1
);

$client = new SoapClient($url.'?wsdl', $options);

$document = file_get_contents('retursvar.xml');

$params = array('SubmitDocument' => $document);
$response = $client->__soapCall('submitDocument', $params);
```

but I get this error in the Apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [bpws:forcedTermination] business exception in /var/www/html/soaptest.php:15\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/soaptest.php(15): SoapClient->__soapCall('submitDocument', Array)\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/soaptest.php on line 15
```

If i call:

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

immediately after:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url.'?wsdl', $options);
```

I get this output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(62) "SubmitDocumentResponse submitDocument(SubmitDocument $payload)" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It says that you haven't caught an exception. Try wrapping your code inside try catch block.

Comment: If I catch the SoapFault, I get this in my browser: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://oes.dk/NemKonto/NemKontoReceiveService"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:SubmitDocument/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`